# Replace value based on match between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have two starting data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(code1 = c("a", "b","z"), code2 = c("2", "3", "4"))
df2 <- data.frame(code1 = c("c", "o", "p"), code2 = c("2", "4", "5"), 
                  column3 = "a", column4 = "b", column5 = "c")
```

I want to match the two data frames by the column 'code2' and where that's a match, replace the value of code1 in df1 to the value of code1 in df2 so that the final data frame looks like this:

```
df3<- data.frame(code1 = c("c", "b", "o"), code2 = c("2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/). It "looks up" `code1` in `df2`, wherever `code2` matches; and when no match is found, it defaults to the original `code1` in `df1`.

## Solution

```
library(dplyr)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df1' and 'df2'.
# ...


df1 %>% mutate(code1 = coalesce(
  # Look up the 'code1' according to 'code2'...
  df2$code1[match(code2, df2$code2)],
  # ...and otherwise default to the original 'code1'.
  code1
))
```

## Result

Given `df1` and `df2` as in your example

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  code1 = c("a", "b","z"),
  code2 = c("2", "3", "4")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  code1 = c("c", "o", "p"),
  code2 = c("2", "4", "5"),
  column3 = "a",
  column4 = "b",
  column5 = "c"
)
```

this solution should yield the desired result:

```
  code1 code2
1     c     2
2     b     3
3     o     4
```

## Note

One advantage of using [`match()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/match.html) rather than a [`dplyr::*_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html): no additional steps are needed to purge extraneous columns from your results.

Answer (score 3):

Using `left_join` and `coalesce`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2[,c(1,2)], by = "code2") %>% 
  transmute(code1 = coalesce(code1.y, code1.x), 
            code2 = code2)
#>   code1 code2
#> 1     c     2
#> 2     b     3
#> 3     o     4
```